# Picker list in Manipulator resets to NULL after a selection is made (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to generate plots using manipulator function where the picker list would choose certain rows (which I am passing as a list to the picker) from a table. When I run the manipulator, it is showing the plot perfectly fine for the first selection but after I make a selection it is giving me the following error:-

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'    
3: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'    
4: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf   
5: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 
6: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf   
7: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Following is my code:-

```
Bivariate_Plots_cont=function(base_table,Table)
{
  c<- subset(base_table$segment_per_book, base_table$var_name==Table)
  print(c)
  plot(c, type="b", col="red", 
   axes=FALSE, xlab="Decile Starting Value", ylab="Event Rate (%)",main=Table,xaxt="n")

  axis(1, at=1:10,labels=subset(base_table$min,     base_table$var_name==Table),cex.axis=0.5)
  par(new=TRUE)

  plot(subset(base_table$per_distribution, base_table$var_name==Table), type="b",   col="blue", 
   axes=TRUE, xlab="", ylab="",xaxt="n")
}



Set_Factors_cont=function(base_table)
{
  Variables<<- unique(base_table$var_name)
  Factors <<- as.list(as.character(Variables))
}


Set_Factors_cont(cont3)


manipulate(
  Bivariate_Plots_cont(cont3,Table),
  Table=picker(Factors)
  )
```

Basically in the above three-piece code, I am defining a wrapper function-Bivariate_Plots_cont that combines two plots and am calling it inside the manipulator passing "Factors" as a list to the picker option.

Comment: Seems like picker is being called incorrectly. It takes the ... arguments and converts them, not a list. You can likely do something like: `do.call(picker, lapply(Factor, identity))` to work around this.

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for the idea. But passing as a list worked fine for me in sample datasets I used. I got the idea from the following link:-http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/270-choosing-axes-with-manipulate

Comment: Is this manipulate from the manipulate package?  I believe that is RStudio specific and if this is the case you should mention it in the question.  Either way you should make it clear where you get manipulate from since it's not a part of base R.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes it its manipulate part of the R-Studio. I installed the manipulate package to use the same.